# xml to xml transformation using xslt based on parent and child relationship

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to transform my xml to another xml based on parent and child relationship.

Below is my source xml

```
<FIXML>
    <Header>
        <RequestID>ReqID8942</RequestID>
    </Header>
    <Body>
     <Data>
      <LimitDetails>
        <LimitRefNo>L1</LimitRefNo>
        <LimitClassification>ROOT</LimitClassification>
        <ParentLimitRefNo></ParentLimitRefNo>
        <ApprovedLimit>100.0</ApprovedLimit>
      </LimitDetails>
      <LimitDetails>
        <LimitRefNo>L2</LimitRefNo>
        <LimitClassification>ClASSIFICATION1</LimitClassification>
        <ParentLimitRefNo>L1</ParentLimitRefNo>
        <ApprovedLimit>200.0</ApprovedLimit>
      </LimitDetails>
      <LimitDetails>
        <LimitRefNo>L3</LimitRefNo>
        <LimitClassification>CLASSIFICATION2</LimitClassification>
        <ParentLimitRefNo>L2</ParentLimitRefNo>
        <ApprovedLimit>300.0</ApprovedLimit>
      </LimitDetails>
      <LimitDetails>
        <LimitRefNo>L4</LimitRefNo>
        <LimitClassification>CLASSIFICATION3</LimitClassification>
        <ParentLimitRefNo>L3</ParentLimitRefNo>
        <ApprovedLimit>400.0</ApprovedLimit>
      </LimitDetails>
      </Data>
   </Body>
</FIXML>
```

Here,Child limits refers Parent limits based on ParentLimitRefNo. Parent limit is the one which has ParentLimitRefNo as empty.

Below is the xml which i need to produce based on source xml.

```
<FIXML>
    <Header>
        <RequestID>ReqID8942</RequestID>
    </Header>
    <Body>
     <Data>
      <LimitDetails>
        <Limit>
           <LimitRefNo>L1</LimitRefNo>
           <LimitClassification>ROOT</LimitClassification>
           <ParentLimitRefNo></ParentLimitRefNo>
           <ApprovedLimit>100.0</ApprovedLimit>
           <SubLimit>
             <LimitRefNo>L2</LimitRefNo>
             <LimitClassification>ClASSIFICATION1</LimitClassification>
             <ParentLimitRefNo>L1</ParentLimitRefNo>
             <ApprovedLimit>200.0</ApprovedLimit>
         <SubLimit>
           <LimitRefNo>L3</LimitRefNo>
               <LimitClassification>CLASSIFICATION2</LimitClassification>
               <ParentLimitRefNo>L2</ParentLimitRefNo>
               <ApprovedLimit>300.0</ApprovedLimit>
           <SubLimit>
              <LimitRefNo>L4</LimitRefNo>
              <LimitClassification>CLASSIFICATION3</LimitClassification>
                  <ParentLimitRefNo>L3</ParentLimitRefNo>
                  <ApprovedLimit>400.0</ApprovedLimit> 
           </SubLimit>
        </SubLimit>
       </SubLimit>
      </Limit>
    </LimitDetails>
  </Data>
</Body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation (easy to convert to XSLT 1.0)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kLD" match="LimitDetails" use="ParentLimitRefNo"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Data">
  <Data>
    <LimitDetails>
        <xsl:apply-templates
        select="LimitDetails[not(ParentLimitRefNo/node())]"/>
    </LimitDetails>
  </Data>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="LimitDetails">
  <xsl:variable name="vSuf" select=
    "if(ParentLimitRefNo/text())
       then 'Sub'
       else ()
    "/>

  <xsl:element name="{$vSuf}Limit">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|key('kLD', LimitRefNo)"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<FIXML>
    <Header>
        <RequestID>ReqID8942</RequestID>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Data>
            <LimitDetails>
                <LimitRefNo>L1</LimitRefNo>
                <LimitClassification>ROOT</LimitClassification>
                <ParentLimitRefNo></ParentLimitRefNo>
                <ApprovedLimit>100.0</ApprovedLimit>
            </LimitDetails>
            <LimitDetails>
                <LimitRefNo>L2</LimitRefNo>
                <LimitClassification>ClASSIFICATION1</LimitClassification>
                <ParentLimitRefNo>L1</ParentLimitRefNo>
                <ApprovedLimit>200.0</ApprovedLimit>
            </LimitDetails>
            <LimitDetails>
                <LimitRefNo>L3</LimitRefNo>
                <LimitClassification>CLASSIFICATION2</LimitClassification>
                <ParentLimitRefNo>L2</ParentLimitRefNo>
                <ApprovedLimit>300.0</ApprovedLimit>
            </LimitDetails>
            <LimitDetails>
                <LimitRefNo>L4</LimitRefNo>
                <LimitClassification>CLASSIFICATION3</LimitClassification>
                <ParentLimitRefNo>L3</ParentLimitRefNo>
                <ApprovedLimit>400.0</ApprovedLimit>
            </LimitDetails>
        </Data>
    </Body>
</FIXML>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<FIXML>
   <Header>
      <RequestID>ReqID8942</RequestID>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <Data>
         <LimitDetails>
            <Limit>
               <LimitRefNo>L1</LimitRefNo>
               <LimitClassification>ROOT</LimitClassification>
               <ParentLimitRefNo/>
               <ApprovedLimit>100.0</ApprovedLimit>
               <SubLimit>
                  <LimitRefNo>L2</LimitRefNo>
                  <LimitClassification>ClASSIFICATION1</LimitClassification>
                  <ParentLimitRefNo>L1</ParentLimitRefNo>
                  <ApprovedLimit>200.0</ApprovedLimit>
                  <SubLimit>
                     <LimitRefNo>L3</LimitRefNo>
                     <LimitClassification>CLASSIFICATION2</LimitClassification>
                     <ParentLimitRefNo>L2</ParentLimitRefNo>
                     <ApprovedLimit>300.0</ApprovedLimit>
                     <SubLimit>
                        <LimitRefNo>L4</LimitRefNo>
                        <LimitClassification>CLASSIFICATION3</LimitClassification>
                        <ParentLimitRefNo>L3</ParentLimitRefNo>
                        <ApprovedLimit>400.0</ApprovedLimit>
                     </SubLimit>
                  </SubLimit>
               </SubLimit>
            </Limit>
         </LimitDetails>
      </Data>
   </Body>
</FIXML>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Using and modifying the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.
2. Using a **[key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key)** to specify all logical children of a `LimitDetails` from its `LimitRefNo`.

---

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

This is an almost mechanical translation of the above transformation into XSLT 1.0 -- only the definition of the variable `$vSuf` is different:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kLD" match="LimitDetails" use="ParentLimitRefNo"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Data">
  <Data>
    <LimitDetails>
        <xsl:apply-templates
        select="LimitDetails[not(ParentLimitRefNo/node())]"/>
    </LimitDetails>
  </Data>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="LimitDetails">
  <xsl:variable name="vSuf" select=
  "concat('',
          substring('Sub',1 div boolean(ParentLimitRefNo/text()))
         )"/>

  <xsl:element name="{$vSuf}Limit">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|key('kLD', LimitRefNo)"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied to the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced.**

Comment: if i use XSLT1.0 solution which you guided me,i m getting four <Sublimit> open & closing tag but i need three <Sublimit> open and closing tag.pls help me.

Comment: if i use XSLT2.0 solution which you provided me,             
I m getting an error. ERROR: 'Syntax error in 'if(ParentLimitRefNo/text()) then 'Sub' else () '.' FATAL ERROR: 'Could not compile stylesheet'. I need one parent <Limit> tag and three <Sublimit> open and closing tag in the output.please help me.

Comment: @Moorthy, Your statement **is not true** as shown in the answer, the result contains exactly 3 `SubLimit` elements. As for getting an error "compiling the stylesheet", Are you sure that you really have an XSLT 2.0 processor? I always verify that my solutions run and produce the correct result. In fact, I just copy and paste the real result into the answer.

Comment: ,I think i m using XSLT1.0 processor.I will update it XSLT2.0 and will update you soon.I m learing XSLT now based on your coding strategy.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Moorthy, the author of the other answer has asked you to *accept* the best of the answers. Accepting is done by clicking the check-mark next to the answer. As only one of the answers can be accepted, and to help you making an informed decision, I want to highlight some advantages of using my code -- it is shorter, key-based -- that is much more efficient, and more DRY -- doesn't contain a single `<xsl:if>` or other XSLT conditional instruction. You might not have noticed, that I provide an XSLT 1.0 solution, too, and it has all plusses of its XSLT 2.0 cousin.

Answer (score 1):

The use of keys surely is more elegant (see Dimitre Novatchevs solution), but this one takes the wanted changes in the structure into account (e.g. rename `<LimitDetails />` to `<SubLimit />` and placing the `<Limit />` tag.):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <LimitDetails>
            <Limit>
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".//LimitDetails[./ParentLimitRefNo='']" />
            </Limit>
        </LimitDetails>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LimitDetails">
    <xsl:variable name="LimitRefNo" select="./LimitRefNo" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    <xsl:if test="../LimitDetails[./ParentLimitRefNo = $LimitRefNo]">
    <SubLimit>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../LimitDetails[./ParentLimitRefNo = $LimitRefNo]" />
    </SubLimit>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Or as a modification of Dimitre's solution using keys:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kLD" match="LimitDetails" use="ParentLimitRefNo"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Data">
  <Data>
    <LimitDetails>
      <Limit>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="LimitDetails[not(ParentLimitRefNo/node())]"/>
      </Limit>
    </LimitDetails>
  </Data>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="LimitDetails">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  <xsl:if test="key('kLD', LimitRefNo)">
  <SubLimit>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kLD', LimitRefNo)"/>
  </SubLimit>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is a small issue. i m getting four </Sublimit> closing tag but there is only three <sublimit> open tag.pls help me.

Comment: is there any possibility to remove <SubLimit /> tag from output xml? <SubLimit><LimitRefNo>L4</LimitRefNo><ParentLimitRefNo>L3</ParentLimitRefNo><SubLimit /></SubLimit>

Comment: hielsnoppe, one of the two transformations in your answer produces compilation error and the second produces wrong result.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I'm highly interested in why you get an error, because when I test them using either PHP or Java both transformations work correctly, apart from what Moorthy mentioned above.

Comment: @Moorthy I just updated the transformation to account for what you mentioned above. Does it work for you?

Comment: @hielsnoppe, try copy+paste -- on a computer that is not yours, then run the transformations -- you'll get the error on the first transformation. As for the wrong result from the second, you don't need another computer -- just observe the result and compare with the wanted one.

Comment: I think what Dimitre's not telling you is that you first transformation has an `<xsl:include>` in it. It looks like that's just the identity transform, it's pretty easy to substitute that in, and your answer's just fine if you do. I can't see anything wrong with your second answer either, although admittedly I didn't check every single character. I doubt Dimitre will explain what's wrong though, he rarely does.

Comment: Now I see, I forgot to replace the include with the identity template. I'll fix that in a minute.

Comment: @hielsnoppe,I tried with second transformation. its giving me proper result what i expected. thanks a lot.you are awesome and reduced most of my efforts.

Comment: You are welcome! Whenever you think an answer solves your problem best, you might consider to hit the green check mark to mark the answer accepted.

Comment: @hielsnoppe, OK, I see that you have edited the answer and corrected that error -- your original code was producing empty `SubLimit` elements.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I ask him to accept whatever answer suits him best. If I recall correctly, the first versions of your answer had some flaws, too. I appreciate your knowledge and willingness to share it with others, but I think there is little value to having a go at each other like you do, is there?

Comment: @hielsnoppe, I apologize that at the time I wrote that comment I hadn't noticed that you had already fixed the error I was referring to. I also relied on a little sense of humor on your side and accompanied the comment with a smile :). I have deleted the comment that obviously upset you.